# Versioning application number

Tags: c#, wpf, version-control, versioning

A project I have recently taken over is a desktop application with alot of class assemblies.
It is a WPF desktop application.

There are multiple releases of the application and each has a version no. as normal ( 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1 etc... )

This version number of the overall application is taken from the 'Views.dll' only. 
ie: The application version number is defined by the version number in the views class assembly. ( Used to display in an 'About' dialog window in the application UI.

All other assemblys can have a different version. So if the views is 1.2.1, the other assemblies can be 1.0 and dont ever have to change.

My question is, is this the correct way to define the application version number? 
ie: Using a single assembly's version number to be the version number for the application? Or is is one of many methods?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973869.aspx) outlines the best practices quite clearly.

Comment: I don't think there is a "correct" way, so to speak. What you're describing is pretty common. You need to develop your own set of standards. My team doesn't really care about version numbers so as long as all the libraries have the same major version number  we're happy. Do what you feel makes sense.

Comment: See this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099129/publish-version-vs-assembly-etc-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things easily traceable i prefer to change the version of all assemblies same as the parent assembly. If there has any assembly used by multiple projects. I do not change the version of that until i make some changes to it.

Comment: Similar to what I have been doing also, as mentioned in my original question where the Views.dll is the 'user facing' version, I too changed the other class assemblies to be the same version. Those assemblies are not used by other projects therefor the version number change has no impact. Thanks